# Walmart Api Integration with Laravel 7 and Auto Digital Signature Creation

Tags: laravel-7, guzzle, walmart-api

I am working on Walmart Api Integration, using Laravel 7. I had installed the GuzzleHttp too. I used DigitalSignatureUtil.jar to generate WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE and WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP. It works fine to fetch data in json at first time. The following is the code.

```
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/feeds', [
        'headers' => [
            'WM_SVC.NAME' => 'walmart market place',
            'WM_CONSUMER.ID' => '#########',
            'WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID' => '########',
            'WM_CONSUMER.CHANNEL.TYPE' => '######',               
            'WM_SEC.AUTH_SIGNATURE' => '#######',
            'WM_SEC.TIMESTAMP' => '1596290047006',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ]
    ]);
    $products = json_decode((string) $res->getBody(), true);

    return view('product', compact('products'));
```

NOTE: But it gives errors if i use the code next day, or after few minutes. I get following error

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
Client error: `GET https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/feeds` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` 
response: {"error": [{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED.GMP_GATEWAY_API",
"field":"UNAUTHORIZED","description":"Unauthorized","info":"Unauthorize (truncated...)
```

Please help me what should i do to get rid from this?

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all.  I thought that method of authentication was depreciated last year.  Now they're using OAuth.  See: https://developer.walmart.com/#/apicenter/marketPlace/latest#apiAuthentication

Comment: The AUTH_SIGNATURE is time based, and will expire within 5 miinutes.  Be sure to refresh it.

Comment: how i can automatic refresh the AUTH_SIGNATURE on every post or get api calls?

Comment: How?  What part of doing that are you having trouble with?  That may be a separate question.

Comment: i was talking about the same code which mentioned above? well if i use OAuth will it be helpful?

Comment: I don't see where you're calling the DigitalSignatureUtil.jar.  I found OAuth to be easier.

Comment: I manually generated the Auth_Signature using DigitalSignature and putted the values in above code. Do you have any link or a sample code to use OAuth for walmart API? please

Comment: I have no code for laravel, sorry.

Comment: for which you have available share it for knowledge if possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are plenty of examples and better samples than I have.  Take a look, try it, and if you get stuck, post another question.